# AngularJS binding not updating model

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-ng-model

I recently started exploring AngularJS. I saw some similar questions but I'm quite sure that there isn't any scope problem here. (or maybe my understanding of scope isn't clear.)

JS Code:

```
var app = angular.module("myApp", []);
app.controller("myController", function($scope){
$scope.b=50000
$scope.apr=10
$scope.hc=$scope.b/$scope.apr
...
})
```

HTML:

```
<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myController">
<span class="inp-heading">b:</span>
<input ng-model="b" type="number" step="1000" min="0" />
<input ng-model="apr" type="number" step="1" min="0" />
{{b}} <br /> <!-- this updates on input value change -->
{{hc}} <br /> <!-- this does NOT update on input value change -->
{{b/apr}} <br /> <!-- this updates on input value change -->
```

As mentioned in the comments (in the HTML code above) $scope.hc doesn't change. This isn't the only issue actually, I'm facing similar trouble while binding array values to input boxes.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: It would be great if you comment before down voting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since controller function is not going to be reinvoked when you just change some of the models, the value of `$scope.hc` won't be recalculated. You need to update it manually or get recalculated value somehow before rendering. Couple of approaches.

### 1. ngChange directive

Use [ngChange](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngChange) directive (kind of onchange event) to update `$scope.hc` value:

```
var app = angular.module("myApp", []);
app.controller("myController", function($scope){
  $scope.b = 50000
  $scope.apr = 10
  $scope.hc = $scope.b/$scope.apr

  $scope.onChange = function () {
    $scope.hc = $scope.b/$scope.apr
  }
})
```

HTML

```
<input ng-model="b" ng-change="onChange()" type="number" step="1000" min="0" />
<input ng-model="apr" ng-change="onChange()" type="number" step="1" min="0" />
```

### 2. Using getter

You can use old gold ES5 property getter here when [defining](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/defineProperty) `hc` as a property of $scope object:

```
var app = angular.module("myApp", []);
app.controller("myController", function($scope){
  $scope.b = 50000
  $scope.apr = 10

  Object.defineProperty($scope, 'hc', {
    get: function () {
      return $scope.b/$scope.apr
    }
  })
})
```

HTML won't change in this case.

Answer (score 1):

your `hc` won't update automatically, if needed then it should be a function like

```
var app = angular.module("myApp", []);
app.controller("myController", function($scope){
  $scope.b=50000
  $scope.apr=10
  $scope.hc= function() { return $scope.b/$scope.apr; };
  ...
})
```

and then in your partial it should be (instead of `hc`, it will be `hc()`)

```
<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myController">
<span class="inp-heading">b:</span>
<input ng-model="b" type="number" step="1000" min="0" />
<input ng-model="apr" type="number" step="1" min="0" />
{{b}} <br /> 
{{hc()}} <br /> 
{{b/apr}} <br />
```

Comment: Why was the expression not being updated automatically when values were changed?

Comment: bcoz the scope value `hc` is initialized from the values of b and apr, the value of the is expression stored for `hc`, not the expression